# Total values for each item with consecutive dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I try to calculate the total values of each “line” as below, however, the calculation just contains the consecutive dates.
 I try to use “sumif” function but cannot manage the consecutive dates condition:

```
Date               | Line   |Performance
-------------------|--------|------------------
02-May-2017        |   X    |10
02-May-2017        |   Y    |82
03-May-2017        |   X    |31
03-May-2017        |   Z    |25
03-May-2017        |   K    |15
04-May-2017        |   Y    |60
05-May-2017        |   Y    |75
05-May-2017        |   K    |66
05-May-2017        |   Z    |43
06-May-2017        |   Y    |56
06-May-2017        |   Z    |67
```

[image]

The expected result:

```
X = 41 (2, 3 May 2017 as consecutive dates)
Y = 191 (4,5,6 May 2017)
Z = 110 (5,6 May 2017)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you have more than 1 calculation with consecutive dates?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a helper column (let's make it in `D:D`) to determine whether the row belongs to a consecutive range:

```
=OR(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2-1,$B:$B,$B2)>0,COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2+1,$B:$B,$B2)>0)
```

Then you calculate the sum by `X, Y, Z` like this:

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,"X",$D:$D,TRUE)
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,"Y",$D:$D,TRUE)
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,"Z",$D:$D,TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

CustomX's comment remains to be resolved.

Until then, and assuming you put your *Line* of choice, e.g. "X", in `E2`, **array formula**** in `F2`:

`=SUM(IF(B$2:B$12=E2,IF(MMULT(0+ISNUMBER(MATCH(A$2:A$12-{1,-1},IF(B$2:B$12=E2,A$2:A$12),0)),{1;1}),C$2:C$12)))`

Copy down to give similar results for *Lines* in `E3`, `E4`, etc.

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, you first hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, and only then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*